# Android Firebase Data Retrieving map correctly without no spacing between words

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I need to retrieve data (two words - Mega building) from Firebase correctly. However,
**"Mega building"** is retrieved as **"Megabuilding"**. As seen, it happens without space between two words. Is there any solution for this to draw data like **"Mega building"**? or Can it be done without space, is there an alternative solution when retrieving JSON object data?

Firebase node:

```
My node;
Pro_:
     Basket:
        ID_1:
           cat: “ Titan Tech”
           info:”Mega Building” 
           orderid:”Ref_1” 
        ID_2:
           cat: “Tech”
           info:”Android” 
           orderid:”Ref_2” 
     name:”Mike”
```

My function:

```
Intent intent=this.getIntent();
Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
Map<String, Object> map1 = (Map)bundle.getSerializable(“basket”);

//First output
System.out.println(“My_basket:”+map1.values());

for (Object value : map1.values()) {
    JSONObject json = null;
    try {
        json = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(value).replaceAll(" ",""));
        String cat_ = json.getString(“cat”);
        String info_ = json.getString(“info”);
        String orderid_ = json.getString(“orderid”);

    //Second output
        System.out.println(“Info_:”+info_);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
//Third output
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

First output:

```
My_basket:[{cat=Titan Tech, info=Mega Building, orderid=Ref_1,}, {cat=Tech, info=Android, orderid=Ref_2,}]
```

Second output (ı want to retrieve like “Mega Building”. Problem line is here)

```
Info_: MegaBuilding
```

Third output

```
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 23 of etc
```

Comment: The line `json = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(value).replaceAll(" ",""));` replaces all spaces with nothing. Is this not the behaviour you need?

Comment: You probably added the `.replaceAll(" ","")` to get it working without proper quotation, but as you noted it breaks the contents by removing all the spaces. Your JSON string needs quoted entries if they have spaces in them, like `info: "Mega Building"` (make sure they are ascii quotes, the text you posted in the question has non-ascii quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to mark the spaces where there are spaces.

```
json = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(value).replaceAll(" ","-"));
```

> Output : Mega-Building

Then just replace the marker you created with spaces again. That's it.

```
info_ = info_.replace("-"," ");
```

> Output : Mega Building